# Building a custom class decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x

I thought I understood this, but clearly I don't.

I have a context manager that wraps suites of code inside some metadata handling. The details of that don't matter, suffice to say the code needs to be between a push_job() and pop_job(). That all works, so I can say:

```
with JobManager(*config) as job:
    <Processing Goes Here>
<Follow up processing, not connected to the job>
```

I thought it would be neat if, instead of inserting the `with` statement when an entire function needed to be in its own job context, I could just use the same class as a decorator, and say:

```
@JobManager
def process_job(job, *other_args, *other_kwargs):
```

But it's not working as a decorator, and I can't see why. I get confusion of arguments between the decorator and the wrapped function.

Here's the code:

```
class JobManager(ContextDecorator, AbstractContextManager):
    """Convenience class that provides both a context manager to surround code
    suites needing a new job frame (using push_job()/pop_job()), and a
    decorator to wrap functions in the current frame automagically
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._func, self._args = (
            (args[0], args[1:] if len(args) > 1 else [])
            if args and callable(args[0])
            else (None, args)
        )
        self._kwargs = kwargs

    def __call__(self, func):
        """Called when using JobManager as a decorator. Returns a new frame."""
    
        @wraps(func)
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            with self._recreate_cm() as job_:
                return func(job_, *args, **kwargs)
    
        return inner

    def __enter__(self):
        """Called when using JobManager as a context manager. Pushes a new
        frame or creates the initial frame from the arguments.
        """
        return (
            push_job(*(self._args), **(self._kwargs))
            if not _jobs else 
            push_job()
            )

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        """Called when using JobManager as a context manager."""
        pop_job()
        return super().__exit__(exc_type, exc_value, traceback)
```

Comment: @Michael M - I removed your edits because they broke my question. In particualr, I said "confustion of arguments between the decorator and the wrapped function" because that's what happens - the decorator throws an error because it gets an argument that is supposed to be for the wrapped function.

Comment: How so? I just changed some spelling and did code highlighting

Answer (score 2):

Doing this:

```
@some_decorator
def func(...):
    ...
```

Is same as doing this:

```
def func(...):
    ...

func = some_decorator(func)
```

So what you are doing is basically `process_job = JobManager(process_job)`. In other words, you just created an instance of `JobManager`. This clearly cannot work, as now `process_job()` will invoke the `__call__()` method of the instance, which will simply return the `inner` function and do nothing.

You need to put your "decorating" logic inside your `__call__()` method, and decorate with `@JobManager()` instead (notice the added `()` there). This is because `__init__()` should not return anything. Otherwise, you can avoid the `inner` wrapper inside your `__call__()` method and do the job directly there:

```
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with self._recreate_cm() as job_:
            return self._func(job_, *args, **kwargs)
```

The only "issue" here is that you lose the benefits of `@wraps`. Also, be careful, because then you will need some sanity checks to make sure that calling a normal `JobManager` instance does not raise exceptions because there is no associated function to run.

In any case, I don't see the need for all of this complex fuss. Just define a normal decorator that is a function and leverage the closure of the function to do whatever you need.

```
def managed(func):
    # You could also create the JobManager here if you want
    # e.g. job = JobManager(), and then use it in the wrapper,
    # but that'd need manual enter/exit.

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*a, **kwa):
        with JobManager() as job:
            return func(job, *a, **kwa)

    return wrapper

@managed
def process_job(job, ...):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Marco's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74324732/3936044) addresses your issue nicely. I'd just like to share my version of the decorator and context manager hybrid from my open source [library](https://github.com/ManderaGeneral/generallibrary) `pip install generallibrary`

Definition for `DecoContext` is [here](https://github.com/ManderaGeneral/generallibrary/blob/66ea64896664527943bbd43d2dae4bdd127dc196/generallibrary/context.py#L7)

It would let you write your use case very cleanly like this:

```py
from generallibrary import DecoContext

class JobManager(DecoContext):
    def before(self):
        push_job()

    def after(self):
        pop_job()
```

Lots of test cases [here](https://github.com/ManderaGeneral/generallibrary/blob/66ea64896664527943bbd43d2dae4bdd127dc196/generallibrary/test/test_context.py)

Defining the `__get__` method to return a bound `__call__` method is vital to be able to decorate methods